# Append array int to a string array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

I have a string array that displays a string on an individual line. I would like to take an int array and display on the same line. So the entries of the array are paired in order. So `yourArray[1] = number[1]`, `yourArray[2] = number[2]`, etc. So I am just trying to add a the number array to `labez.text = sortedArray.map { " ($0)" }.joined(separator:"\n")` line of code.

```
var yourArray = [String]()
var number = [Int]()


@IBAction func store(_ sender: Any) {
  yourArray.append((textA.text!))
  number.append(Int(textB.text!)!)

  labez.text = sortedArray.map { " \($0)" }.joined(separator:"\n")


  let sortedArray:[String] = yourArray.sorted {
    $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending 
  }

}
```

Comment: There might be a clever use of map available, but you could also just go old school and use a for loop to enumerate both arrays at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can join two arrays:

```
let a = ["a","b","c","b"]
let b = [1,2,3,4]

let d = a.enumerated().map { (index,string) -> String in
  guard  b.count > index else { return "" }
  return "\(b[index]) \(string)"
}

// d = ["1 a", "2 b", "3 c", "4 b"]
```

Comment: Will this still work if the string array has dupes?  And is performance an issue by using indexOf so frequently?

Comment: Good point @conarch, dupes are a problem, will fix shortly. Regarding `indexOf` I think you need to check on real data, otherwise feels like premature optimization.

Comment: @conarch I edited my answer, what do you think? Works with dupes and doesn't use `indexOf`

Comment: Nice @njuri!  I'm glad I looked at this question, because I learned something new. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is with the `zip` function, you can try this in a playground:

```
let a = ["a","b","c","b"]
let b = [1,2,3,4]

let list = zip(a, b).map{ $0 + " \($1)" }

list // -> ["a 1", "b 2", "c 3", "b 4"]
```

I'm ziping the two arrays, which returns a sequence, and then using the `reduce` method to transform the sequence of `(String, Int)` tuples into a string array.

Comment: `let list = zip(a, b).map { "\($0) \($1)" }`

Comment: Nice one, don't know how I missed it @vacawama, but thanks for pointing it out.